# Creating a column based on matches from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with a column of job titles and the company name in the same string of each row, I also have a list of all possible company names.

How do I search the column of my data frame to see if it contains one of the companies in my list and then create a new column with just the company names if there is a match in some rows? Attached two photos.

[image]

[image]

I tried a few solutions but can't find one that works.

The original logic I followed is;
df['Company'] = df['Title'].str.contains(x for x in joblist) 
but obviously that throws an error.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with joined values by `|` for regex `or` for test values:

```
df['test'] = df['Title'].str.contains('|'.join(joblist))
```

and if want extract values by list use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Company'] = df['Title'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(joblist)})', expand=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access all the items in the list with companies and compare them with each value of column "Title".
You can check if a String contains another String using operator `in`.

```
all_titles = df['Title']
for x in all_titles:
    for y in df:
        if (y in x ):
            //your code here
```

Comment: I think both of those options will work but with the list version I get and error unbalanced parenthesis at position 8466 and with the series option  I get bad escape \C at position 9401...so the list/series are dirty but I cant find the problem I replaced some obvious characters like 's causing issues....any suggestions